# when class add call my function or event

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I have used auto-complete jQuery as like [this](http://www.htmlblog.us/jquery-autocomplete). Its working perfect but now i have add image too in this search result as like image1.png. Now user will select result then image will also be display in text-box. I have made for click event not from select event.When user will click the result i have set the BG image of text bow. I want to select too.

[image: Image 1]

[image]

Below My jQuery Code

```
jQuery(".ui-menu-item").live("click",function(){
    var pr = jQuery('img',this).attr('src');
    jQuery('#zipsearch').css('background-image', 'url(' + pr + ')');
});

jQuery('#ui-active-menuitem').live("hover", function() {
         var pr = jQuery('img',this).attr('src');
    jQuery('#zipsearch').css('background-image', 'url(' + pr + ')');
    });
```

Comment: The .live function is deprecated since version 1.7, use .on() instead

Comment: It is not clear, you want the envelope as background of textbox?  or ??

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My Question is i want text with image in text box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the custom data example of the jQuery autocomplete documentation.

http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data

Skype is doing it in the exakt same way, they just styled it with CSS to look like the flag is inside the input. But the input is next to the a div where they place the flag and they surround it by a div with a border.

```
.container{
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  height: 40px;
}
#project{
  height: 34px;
  width: auto;
  border: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JAT2a/

Here is a small jsFiddle to demonstrate it:

Answer (score 1):

1. You cannot have `img` tags or other within `input` tag.
2. If you have inspected skype approach, you would have found they were using inpu within `li` tags.

Here is my approach.

1) My HTML setup is like

```
<ul class="email-textbox">    
    <li id="images"><img src=""/></li>
    <li><input id="auto" type="text" /></li>
</ul>
```

2) I don't remember where I get this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rK7TS/), based on it I have modified to work on it.  Below is the code I've added

```
  select: function(i, j){           
            var d  = j.item. avatar;
            $('#images img').prop('src', d);
        }
```

**`select`** is a default method of jQuery UI autocomplete, where you can write actions to be performed after selecting an option.

**1. Before selection**

[image]
**2. After selection, image is added**

[image]

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UeTDw/257/)